# Can not makePersistent on GAE/J project with JDO2 on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I tried creating a new GAE/J project with JDO2 on IntelliJ IDEA, but it does not work well because of the following org.datanucleus.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException:

```
The class "Book" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.
```

I also tried creating the exactly same project on Eclipse and it works well without any problems. The created model is very simple as follows (I think this model is non-related):

```java
@PersistenceCapable
public class Book {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced
>   version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an
>   unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are
>   not found." is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been
>   enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the
>   CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data
>   for the class is not found.

The message is pretty clear IMHO. You have to enhance your classes and have the enhanced version in the CLASSPATH at runtime.